# persist a variable set in header.php all the way down to footer.php

Tags: php, templates, variables

I look up a custom post field value in header.php, and store it in a global variable.

In most of my template files, the includes go like this:

```
include header

...do a bunch of stuff

include sidebar
include footer
```

I can not persist the variable into the footer.php file...

is there any way to do this so that I can avoid having to call back to the database again to look up the custom field value again?

Comment: This is a **PHP** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to declare it first above those includes and globalize it within header or footer before getting or setting the value.

however- in the specific context you're speaking of- getting a custom field value, it's only retrieved from the database on the first call, then cached, so subsequent calls won't hit the database again.

Answer (score 0):

You can...

Create a function in **functions.php** file that asks for the custom field and then outputs it... then you need not include it in the header but can just use it wherever you want...

I assume you know how to retrieve the custom field value, but in any case here is an example from the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mykey', true );
```

I hope its a good solution if I understand you correct.

Cheers, Sagive.

Comment: Thanks for the response... this does not achieve the purpose. The problem is, even if I did as you suggested, I still need to make a call each time to the function, which in turn, makes a call to the db to get the value, right?

I want to load the value into the variable the first time, and have it persist until the end of the footer.php

Comment: that would mean (as far as i know) either creating a session or send it between pages using the url (which is complecated in wordpress)... in any case, a custom field value should be drown from the database... i dont know why people are fearfull to use the DB.. thats why its their :) - its a small query - no harm..